# Why the shapes in the legend are not same as shapes in the plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 version 2.1.0. Following is the screenshot of a plot I created:

[image]

Following is the code:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = BSX_SDX_5 %>% filter(CC1_BX1>0, sp_BX>1,
                                         !(CC1_BX1 %in% c(Inf, -Inf)), 
                                         dV_BX>=-1 & dV_BX<=0,
                                         BX1<=40) ,
             aes(y = dV_BX, x = BX1, shape = "Observed"), alpha=0.4)+
  geom_point(data = modi_CC1 %>% filter(CC1>0, sp_BX>1,
                                        !(CC1 %in% c(Inf, -Inf)),dV<=0,
                                        min_spacing<=76) ,
             aes(y = dV, x = min_spacing, shape = "SIMDATA1"), size=3)+
  geom_point(data = def_CC1 %>% filter(CC1>0, sp_BX>1,
                                        !(CC1 %in% c(Inf, -Inf)),dV<=0,
                                       min_spacing<=76) ,
             aes(y = dV, x = min_spacing, shape = "SIMDATA2"), size=3) + 
  scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 0, 16))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=0.5),
        axis.text  = element_text(size=20),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = c(0.9,0.8),
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

I haven't shared the data as it seems that the problem is not concerned with the data. How can I make sure that shapes in legend correctly correspond with those in the plot?

Comment: Think the issue is with the `legend.key.height`, and `legend.key.width` theme elements, try removing them and see how you go.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton, I removed the whole `theme` part and ran the code. The plot is generated but still have the same problem in shapes.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, its because you are specifying the size = 3 for the last 2 geometries, and no specification for the first one. Try setting all the point geoms with the same size, or remove the size argument completely.

Comment: Thanks. Same size for all 3 fixed the issue. But what if I want to make the first size small. Is that not possible?

Comment: Try mapping to size, and using scale_size_manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the explicit **size** specification in the three geom layers, the first not having any at all, and the 2nd and 3rd geom having size set to 3.

This illustrates my point:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 100
shapes = c("Observed","SIMDATA1","SIMDATA2")
df   = data.frame(x=runif(n),y=runif(n),shape=sample(shapes,n,replace=T))
base = ggplot(df,aes(x,y,shape=shape)) + 
  scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 0, 16))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=0.5),
        axis.text  = element_text(size=20),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = c(0.9,0.8),
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm")) 

#BAD, AS PER YOUR PROBLEM
base + 
  geom_point(data=df[1:(n/2),])+
  geom_point(data=df[(n/2):n,],size=3) 

#GOOD
base + 
  geom_point(data=df[1:(n/2),])+
  geom_point(data=df[(n/2):n,]) 

#GOOD
base + 
  geom_point(data=df[1:(n/2),],size=3)+
  geom_point(data=df[(n/2):n,],size=3)
```

If you want to have distinct sizes, you can map a variable to size, and use `scale_size_manual`, like this:

```
base = ggplot(df,aes(x,y,shape=shape,size=shape)) + 
  scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 0, 16)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3,6,6)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=0.5),
        axis.text  = element_text(size=20),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = c(0.9,0.8),
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm")) 

base + 
  geom_point(data=df[1:(n/2),])+
  geom_point(data=df[(n/2):n,])
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.